# JSON object or JSON string? Which is better to store in database?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm little confused that if I wanna store json objects and arrays in db than which way is better. I can either directly store them as they are or I can first convert it to string with method `JSON.stringify()` and then store it. And reuse it with method `JSON.parse()`.
I'm using cloud firestore as my db and as it has 20K field limits on one document, one thing I concluded is that whichever object has a possibility of having more than 20K fields (e.g. canvas drawings), those should be stored as a string. But still I want to have some more clearity about which method should I prefer for small arrays and objects which would be:

1. Cost effective
2. Optimised in performance
3. Other factors which I don't know

Comment: [JSON](https://json.org/) is **always** a string.

Comment: @NinaScholz JSON is **not** a string. Its a format to store and transform data. You better recheck the link you've sent or google it.

Comment: Your wikipedia link says: **JSON is an open standard file format, and data interchange format**. There's a clear difference between **format** and **string**. Kindly check the information you are sharing. And if its already a string than why we use ```JSON.stringify()``` method to convert any object to string. Please think about it.

Comment: `stringify` takes some javascript type and converts it to a string. the result is JSON. a json file is a string as well (which needs parsing), in opposite of a javascript file (which does not need parsing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore is specifically optimized and marketed for storing JSON objects, which means that if you don't use this format, you are going to miss out on a lot of functionality provided by Firestore and would have to implement it yourself.

For example, storing the user's data as a string (in a JSON format, but without telling Firestore that it is) would mean that you wouldn't be able to use the [powerful firestore query system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), because it won't know which format the data is in, since it's all just a string. Therefore, you would have to fetch all users to the client, and then do queries on that data manually, which means taking up a lot of RAM and network.

When updating, you would have to transfer all bytes of the object's string representation through the network in order to modify even a single small field. If stored as an object, however, you can modify specific fields without the need of transfering the whole payload.